# C# Serialization, put the property's value as element name

Tags: c#, attributes, xml-serialization

I am working on serialize one C# class into XML. The class is shown below:

```
public class EventProperty
{
    private string propertyNameField;
    private string propertyValueField;

    public string PropertyName
    {
        get  { return this.propertyNameField; }
        set  { this.propertyNameField = value; }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]        
    public string PropertyValue
    {
        get { return this.propertyValueField;  }
        set { this.propertyValueField = value; }
    }
}//end class
```

The test code is :

```
propertySet = new List<EventProperty>();
propertySet.Add(new EventProperty() { PropertyName = "ChenYi", PropertyValue = "21" });
propertySet.Add(new EventProperty() { PropertyName = "ChenJida", PropertyValue = "232" });
propertySet.Add(new EventProperty() { PropertyName = "XieChao", PropertyValue = "999" });
```

The result is like:

```
<property>
    <PropertyName>ChenYi</PropertyName>21</property>
<property>
    <PropertyName>ChenJida</PropertyName>232</property>
<property>
    <PropertyName>XieChao</PropertyName>999</property>
```

But i am expecting something like below:

```
<property>
    <ChenYi>21</ChenYi></property>
<property>
    <ChenJida>232</ChenJida></property>
<property>
    <XieChao>999</XieChao></property>
```

Anyone know which xmlattribute should be used here? Or there is another way?

Comment: mmm, why do you need to construct such xml structure? why not just use properly named elements or attributes for your structure? i.e. <student><name>Chen Yi</name><age>21</age></student>

Comment: The XML you are expecting is not valid - element names may not contain spaces.

Comment: what you want has no sense... there will be nothing to parse it back, and that is what are xml build for, universal data transfer...

Comment: ooh, actually I am deserializing the existing XML document to the EventProperty class instance. The original XML document is like:

    <name>value</name>

and ,their is no space in the name filed, the data above is just from my test codes.

Comment: The spaces in the name filed had been removed to avoid misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Custom Serialization Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) if default Xml Serialization behavior is not fulfilling your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, I write the customer serialization behavior for it. It works.